# Tibco with JMS Application

Tags: java, tibco-ems

I want to use tibco in my jms application. Can any one help me how can I use tibco and also please what are the benefits from tibco.

Comment: Surely Tibco is the best people to say why you should use them.  If they can't explain it to you is a way you understand, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: If you want to use a Tibco product then why are you asking the benefits..? Sounds like you already made the decsion.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the samples directory in your Tibco EMS installation directory.  It provides samples for the most common scenarios using the ems libs directly.

If you are using Spring to wire up your messaging there really isn't anything different you do for EMS compared to connnecting to ActiveMQ for example.  Create a MessageListenerContainer or a JMSTemplate and you are on your way.

Comment: Are there any benefits to using the ems libs directly over using the spring jms?

Answer (score 0):

The different between TIBCO EMS and other JMS providers is a BIG question (bascially a trade-off between price, your open-source affinity, 24/7 customer support etc.)

How to use it ?
I would recommend writing your own example JMS consumer, straigth from examples from a good book, for example: Java Message Service, by Richard Monson-Haefel and others.
(this one is small but concise)

and then configure your example with arguments like this:

For TIBCO's EMS JNDI:

-jndiContextFactory com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
   -jndiProviderUrl    tibjmsnaming://localhost:7222
   -topic TEST

..